# Having problems DBContext with Edit/Update MVC 4 EF c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext

I'm still pretty new to EF and MVC 4 and I'm having some problems with manipulating a fairly trivial record update.
What I'm trying to do is essentially make a history of changes done to a record, so often I need to record the previous value of that record somewhere before overwrite it with the new values.

I've been running into Unique key issues, or depending on how I code it the db.savechanges() will create an additional entry when it only should be updating.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(UrlRedirect urlredirect)
    {
        using (var db = new Context())
        {
            UrlRedirect old_url = db.UrlRedirects.Find(urlredirect.ID);
            string notes = old_url.NewUrl;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ChangeRecord cr = new ChangeRecord();
                cr.Author = User.Identity.Name;
                cr.Date = DateTime.Today;
                cr.Change = "Modified";
                cr.UrlRedirect = urlredirect;
                cr.Notes = notes;
                db.ChangeRecords.Add(cr);

                db.Entry<UrlRedirect>(old_url).CurrentValues.SetValues(urlredirect);
                db.Entry(old_url).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(urlredirect);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which field is the *key field* for the record?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud for the UrlRedirect Table it is 'ID'

Comment: @michaelperrenoud sorry I mean I want the NewUrl field - which I have indicated as notes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have access to the database itself? I just created a database table update trigger.

I have a table and an archive table with the same schema. I create a PK on the archive table using the ID and the Sequence number. This does pretty well and I just have to worry about incrementing the sequence number in the main table.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [QAForum].[AnswerUpdate] ON [QAForum].[Answer] AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  INSERT INTO [QAForum].[AnswerArchive] (ID, QuestionID, AuthorID, Sequence, [Message], Rating, IsAnswer, Modified)
  SELECT ID, QuestionID, AuthorID, Sequence, [Message], Rating, IsAnswer, Modified FROM deleted d;
END
```

That way when I do changes to the previous table in my ActionResult I just increment the sequence number and let the database do the rest.

Comment: I do, I will consider this route for sure.  I normally don't do DB procedures, but this trigger should work thanks for providing me some options here.

Comment: @RobertChan You're welcome. I fumbled with this same concept about 6 months ago.